# To find difference between unique levels

Tags: r

I have a column in which I have unique levels ,I want to find the gap (difference between the levels ).

I have data

```
x=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4)
```

The result for this should be :

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can user `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
ave(x, rleid(x), FUN = seq_along)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

Or convert to a `data.table` and then group by the `rleid`

```
data.table(x)[, seq_len(.N), x]$V1
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

Or after using `rle`, extract the `lengths` and apply `sequence`

```
sequence(rle(x)$lengths)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not very clear code, but it gets the job done:

```
res = ifelse(x == 0, 0, ifelse(c(0, x[-length(x)]) != 0, 0, NA))
res[is.na(res)] = with(rle(x == 0), lengths[values])
res
# [1] 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 2 0
```

This is perhaps better:

```
res2 = x
res2[x != 0] = diff(c(0, which(x != 0))) - 1
res2
# [1] 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 2 0
```

Comment: Hi Gregor ,It works ..But if I have data x=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4) .The how to proceed....    The result for this should be : 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 6 and so on

Comment: Oh, I thought you just wanted to count 0's. Perhaps you should edit your question to describe better your process.

Answer (score 2):

Not the definite answer, but her's an approach using rle...

```
x=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,4)

y <- rle(x)

> y
# Run Length Encoding
# lengths: int [1:7] 4 1 4 1 2 1 1
# values : num [1:7] 0 1 0 2 0 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ave` and create a grouping variable with `cumsum` and `diff` to capture the difference in unique levels and create a sequence with `seq_along`

```
ave(x, c(0, cumsum(diff(x) != 0)), FUN = seq_along)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

For the given example, as suggested by @markus this works

```
ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

but what if the input is

```
x=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0)
```

using

```
ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along) #gives
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7
```

whereas

```
ave(x, c(0, cumsum(diff(x) != 0)), FUN = seq_along) #gives
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2
```

Comment: A little simpler `ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along)`

Comment: @markus yes, that works for the given example. However, I had some other case in mind. Updated the answer with that. Thanks :)